# Is it useful to run Ubuntu Friendly off a LiveUSB?

Tags: live-usb

To secure maximum data for [Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/), the maximum number of computers should be tested. However, it is not possible for me (or anyone) to install Ubuntu on all the computers we have access to. Would running Ubuntu Friendly within an Ubuntu LiveUSB give accurate results? For example, some people report certain deficiencies when running Ubuntu off a LiveUSB as opposed to an installation.

Comment: Would also request creation of a ubuntu-friendly tag, or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question fast, Yes.

But I wouldn't suggest it. It is very slow. Also, you have to be careful about running from a live USB flash drive, as they have a limited number of writes you can make to the disk.

And also for the reason that Scott Severance mentioned in his answer.

Running an operating system, like Ubuntu, from your flash drive can be very useful:

1. You can recover your data
2. To scan for viruses
3. Resize partitions
4. System testing

You can run Ubuntu the way you want, even if you don't have your own computer with you. You will have the power of Ubuntu with at all times!

P.S. make sure you use a persistent Ubuntu Live Disk that allows installing additional utilities to run heavy benchmark tests.

Answer (score 3):

In general I think it should work. However, if something forces you to reboot, then your previous testing results will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there might be deficiencies when running from the live CD that will not appear when running with a proper install - every patch that Ubuntu installer downloads during install is a fix for one of those.
So, a system/component running with live CD, will run after full install; a component not running from the live CD MIGHT work after proper install as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all BIOS based machines I would suggest you really install a test installation to a portable hard drive or USB stick and boot that from the boot menu of the BIOS. With UEFI I think it gets a bit more complicated but still manageable. Installing on portable memory is technically no more different from preparing Live USB media, setting up an overlay file system for Live media is also a possible workaround, but over the top.